# An intutive proof of 'replacing two-caps by a handle'

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, string-theory

I am trying to understand a statement given in Polchinski Vol.1 - a torus with cross-cap can be obtained either as (g,b,c) = (0,0,3) or as (1,0,1), trading two cross-caps for a handle.

Here, g is the genus, b is no. of boundaries and c is the no. of cross-caps. I am looking for an intuitive proof of the statement, without involving a lot of mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read Conway's zip proof at
[Conway](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/francisweeks.pdf).

Comment: what (0,0,3) means is that you have a genus three surface and for (1,0,1) is a torus with a projective plane in connected sum

Comment: Okay I think I got my answer, I shall close this section once I read the document.

Comment: do not forget to upvote and accept ; )

Comment: *genus three non-orientable surface for (0,0,3)